# Understanding function objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript  and I am following Douglas Crockford's book, *The Good Parts*.

It says:

*Every function object is also created with a `prototype` property. Its value is an object with a `constructor` property whose value is the function. This is distinct from the hidden link to `Function.prototype`.*

I understand that function objects are linked to `Function.prototype`, but what does the above line mean?

Can someone simplify it for me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Every function object is also created with a `prototype` property.

```
var fn = function() { };
fn.hasOwnProperty("prototype"); // true
```

That is, for every function in JavaScript, each one has a `prototype` property, just like any other JavaScript object.

---

> Its value is an object with a constructor property whose value is the function.

The object that `prototype` points to has a `constructor` property which points to the original function.

```
fn.prototype.constructor === fn // true;
```

That is, you can derive the constructor function from a constructed object by looking at `obj.prototype.constructor` (unless it's been overwritten).

---

> This is distinct from the hidden link to `Function.prototype`

The function you create's `prototype` object is not the same as the `Function's` prototype.

```
fn.prototype != Function.prototype // true
```

That is, if you augment `Function.prototype`, then the methods will be available on function references. If you augment your function's `prototype`, then those methods will be available on constructed objects using that constructor.